# How to set value of an input field using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to show current time within input field. I have used id `local-time`. But in the input field, current time is not showing.

```
Current Time : <input type="text" id = "local-time" value= ""/>
```

```
<script>
setInterval(function() {
var local = new Date();
var localdatetime = local.getHours() + ":" + pad(local.getMinutes()) + ":" + 
pad(local.getSeconds());

$('#local-time').html(localdatetime);
}, 1000);

function pad(t) {
var st = "" + t;

while (st.length < 2)
st = "0" + st;

return st;  
}
</script>
```

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply Edit the script: change `html` to `val`

```
<script>
setInterval(function() {
var local = new Date();
var localdatetime = local.getHours() + ":" + pad(local.getMinutes()) + ":" + 
pad(local.getSeconds());

$('#local-time').val(localdatetime);
}, 1000);

function pad(t) {
var st = "" + t;

while (st.length < 2)
st = "0" + st;

return st;  
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You tried to set the `html` instead of `value` of that input element.

Have a [look at this](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_dom_html_set) for the uses of `.val()` `.html()` `.text()`

```
$('#local-time').val(localdatetime);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
setInterval(function() {
  var local = new Date();
  var localdatetime = local.getHours() + ":" + pad(local.getMinutes()) + ":" + 
  pad(local.getSeconds());

  $('#local-time').val(localdatetime);
}, 1000);

function pad(t) {
   var st = "" + t;

   while (st.length < 2)
   st = "0" + st;

   return st;  
}
```