# Set a value from selector input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with many input

```
$("input[name='firstname']")
```

Return

> Object { 0: input.form-control, 1: input.form-control, 2: input.form-control, 3: input.form-control, length: 4, prevObject: {…} }

I search to set a value to the input, so I tried

```
$("input[name='firstname']")[0].val=12;
$("input[name='firstname']")[0].text=12;
```

I don't see the value in the input.

So I tried

```
$("input[name='firstname']")[0].val("12");
```

Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[0].val is not a function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [find first occurrence of class in div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6423804/find-first-occurrence-of-class-in-div)

Comment: See also [Jquery Setting Value of Input Field](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47235335/215552)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery .eq(index) vs \[index\] if both return an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47341385/jquery-eqindex-vs-index-if-both-return-an-object)

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery function [$(selector)](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1) returns a [jQuery object](https://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery) which acts somewhat like a collection of native elements.

When accessing indexed properties like `[0]`, it returns the native `HTMLElement`.

If you want to just access the first matched element within the object but still have it be a `jQuery` object, use [.eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/). The [.val()](https://api.jquery.com/val/#val2) method lets you safely set the value.

```js
$("input[name=firstname]").eq(0).val(12)
```

Alternately, don't use jQuery at all

```js
// querySelector returns the first match or null
const firstName = document.querySelector("input[name=firstname]");
if (firstName) {
  firstName.value = 12;
}
```